# Cannot set limit of MySQL open-files-limit from 1024 to 65535

Tags: mysql, linux

I have mysql ver. 5.1.49-3, I am working on linux debian. I am trying to set open-files-limit to 65535. so I edited te my.cnf in /etc/mysql/

```
[mysqld]
open_files_limit = 65535
[mysqld_safe]
open_files_limit = 65535
```

then in /etc/security/limit.conf

```
*   soft    nofile  100000
*   hard    nofile  200000
```

After restarting mysql service, when I run this command in linux

```
ps -ef|grep mysql
```

I got 65535. when I log into mysql as root and fetch the value of open-files-limit

```
show global variables like "%open_files_limit%";
```

I got 1024. Please help.

Comment: Is you Operating system having a limit of 1024 (could be the user being limited)?  setting for mysql does not change this.

Comment: Can you please provide steps on how to check from OS the limit?

Comment: I can confirm that the following works:

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/86987/mysql-open-files-limit-cannot-change-this-variable/86988#86988?newreg=71bfff05b6284cb4be6b5b5cdb6c7f45

Comment: Take a look at this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64564698/9731538

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All I need is to add this line to /etc/pam.d/common-session:
`session required pam_limits.so`

then restart apache

Comment: I don't see the connection to apache here... do you meant to say "restart the MySQL server"?

Answer (score 16):

If mysql is started with systemd, this setting is important:

In the file `/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service` you have to add this 2 lines in the `[Service]` section at the end:

```
LimitNOFILE = infinity
LimitMEMLOCK = infinity
```

After this restart systemctl and mysql:

```
systemctl daemon-reload
/etc/init.d/mysql restart
```

To check if the configuration is effective, you can get the parameter from the running mysql process like this:

```
cat /proc/$(pgrep mysqld$)/limits | grep files
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Thank you, fixed it for me.

Answer (score 1):

An issue with older versions of MySQL require you to use use open-files-limit (dashes not underbars) in my.cnf.  See http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=40368

Comment: Yes, already done that. I changed open_files_limit to open-files-limit but nothing happens. It still give me 1024

Comment: Did you change it to use open-files-limit in both the mysqld and mysqld_safe sections?

Comment: Yes i changed it on both mysqld and mysqld_safe

Answer (score 0):

do `ulimit -a` for show. `ulimit -n NUMBER`  can change to YOUR_NUMEBR `open files`

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [official documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_open_files_limit):

> "The value of this variable at runtime is the real value permitted by the system and might be different from the value you specify at server startup."

Answer (score 0):

On Unbuntu 14.04 this worked

```
vim /etc/mysql/my.cnf 

[mysqld]
open-files-limit=16000
```

After this, just restart mysql

```
/etc/init.d/mysql restart
```