# cannot increase open-files-limit in mariadb 10 on centos7

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I searched about the topic subject and tested options, but I still cant increase the open-files-limit on my mariadb server that is used as remote database server for cpanel/whm server.
here is s good reference
http://duntuk.com/how-raise-ulimit-open-files-and-mysql-openfileslimit

I increased it in

```
/etc/my.cnf 

open-files-limit=65550
```

here is some results

```
#ulimit -a 
    core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
    data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
    scheduling priority             (-e) 0
    file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
    pending signals                 (-i) 63471
    max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
    max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
    open files                      (-n) 65535
    pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
    POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
    real-time priority              (-r) 0
    stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
    cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
```

max user processes              (-u) 65535
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited

```
#ulimit -Hn -Sn                              
open files                      (-n) 65535
open files                      (-n) 65535

cat /etc/systemd/system/mariadb.service.d/limits.conf 
[Service]
LimitNOFILE=65500

cat /usr/lib/systemd/system/mariadb.service

[Unit]
Description=MariaDB database server
After=syslog.target
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
User=mysql
Group=mysql
LimitNOFILE=infinity
LimitMEMLOCK=infinity
```

and still in mysql I get

show global variables like 'open%';

+------------------+-------+

| Variable_name    | Value |

+------------------+-------+

| open_files_limit | 1024  |

+------------------+-------+

1 row in set (0.00 sec)

and im getting following error over and over after restart

```
60108 16:30:02 [ERROR] mysqld: Can't open file: './username_wp/wp_users.frm' (errno: 24)
160108 16:30:02 [ERROR] Error in accept: Too many open files
160108 16:30:04 [ERROR] Error in accept: Too many open files
160108 16:30:06 [ERROR] Error in accept: Too many open files
160108 16:30:11 [ERROR] mysqld: Can't open file: './username_db/strikes.frm' (errno: 24)
```

and here is the startup log of mariadb

```
[Warning] Could not increase number of max_open_files to more than 1024 (request: 132107)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

finally i find solution but without any reasonable cause !
i was running MariaDB 5.5 and all settings where fine but the soft limit did not goes more than 1024 !
i was thinking my mariadb is 10.0 as i freshly installed it

after i find out that its 5.5 i tried to upgrade it to v10.0 ! and then BOOM ! problem solved without any extra action or setting ( kernel setting allows maximum files limit as described in reference link )

i hope it help other peoples have same problem ( but after try all other required settings )

Answer (score 4):

RH/CentOS mariadb integration is quiet confusing, using in some places mariadb as its name, mysqld elsewhere...
You should edit(or create) a .conf file in 
/etc/systemd/system/mariadb.service.d/ 
For eg: /etc/systemd/system/mariadb.service.d/centreon.conf

Then edit it as kujiy suggested

```
[Service]
LimitNOFILE=320000
```

Don't forget to reload systemd services files:

`# systemctl daemon-reload`

Cedric

Comment: You can edit a systemd service using `systemd edit <servicename>` which will give you a blank file. Add the content from above and that will override the distribution's main service file. I think this is what is suggested here, but using `systemd edit...` takes the guesswork out of finding the correct location for your distro.

Comment: This didn't work for me. I had to change the `LimitNOFILE` value in the service unit file `/usr/lib/systemd/system/mariadb.service` and remove all mentions of `LimitNOFILE` from files in /etc/systemd/system/mariadb.service.d/. Without that last step, neither the value from the service unit file, nor in e.g. /etc/systemd/system/mariadb.service.d/limits.conf would actually do anything. I also had to set the desired value for `fs.nr_open` in `/etc/sysctl.conf`. Then `systemctl daemon-reload` and `sysctl -p` to load the changes and for safety restart mariadb in 2 steps (stop/start). [CentOS 7]

Answer (score 2):

This is an OS problem.

I think you have to increase the "hard limit" in `/etc/security/limits.conf`, something like this:

```
* hard nofile 65536
* soft nofile 16384
```

then use `ulimit` to increase the "soft limit".

Comment: Hi , Thanks it aleary increased `code`cat /etc/security/limits.conf
`code`mysql soft nofile 65535
`code`mysql hard nofile 65535

`code`* soft nproc 65535
`code` * hard nproc 65535
`code` * soft nofile 65535
`code` * hard nofile 65535`code` but the problem is still there

Comment: Did you change `ulimit`?  Check `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'table%';

Comment: That was output from ulimit; now let's see the new `SHOW` after restarting mariadb server.

Comment: problem is still there 160211 16:30:02 [Warning] Could not increase number of max_open_files to more than 1024 (request: 141323)

Answer (score 1):

You can see the official instruction in the mariadb.service file;

```
[root@db1 system]# cat /usr/lib/systemd/system/mariadb.service | grep exam -A 5
# For example, if you want to increase mariadb's open-files-limit to 10000,
# you need to increase systemd's LimitNOFILE setting, so create a file named
# "/etc/systemd/system/mariadb.service.d/limits.conf" containing:
#       [Service]
#       LimitNOFILE=10000
```

Though I think this should be written in the [official manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_open-files-limit)...

Answer (score 1):

I have CentOS 7.3 with MariaDB 10.0.29 installed from [official repo](http://yum.mariadb.org/10.0/centos7-amd64).

For some reason, systemd unit is named `mysql` and I had to create `/etc/systemd/system/mysql.service.d/oioki.conf`:

```
[Service]
LimitNOFILE=500000
```

Don't forget to run `systemctl daemon-reload` after that.

Answer (score 1):

`open_files_limit` is dynamic value that depends on next params:

```
#my.cnf file

# max connections
max_connections = 64
# table_open_cache = max_connections * tables used in one transaction + 5
table_open_cache = 800
# table_definition_cache = all tables(50) + max_connections + 5
table_definition_cache = 400
# open_files_limit = table_open_cache * 1.4
open_files_limit = 1120
```

To check the value of `open_files_limit` run this command from mysql:

```sql
mysql> select @@open_files_limit;
```

...it will output:

```
+--------------------+
| @@open_files_limit |
+--------------------+
|              12903 |
+--------------------+
1 row in set (0.000 sec)
```

Comment: This worked perfectly well for me in macos catalina. You are a gem!

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem running RedHat Enterprise Linux 7.2 with Software Collections (SCL) and SystemD

```
rh-mariadb100-mariadb-server-10.0.20-1.el7.x86_64
```

In my case the hard limit was ok, but the soft limit was stuck on 1024

Summary of the old and new

```
old : RHEL6.x : MySQL : init.d : mysql_safe : 'root', mysqld : 'mysql'
new : RHEL7.x : MariaDB : SystemD : mysql_safe : 'mysql', mysqld 'mysql'
```

Note that the old initl.d wrapper script runs as root, but the new SystemD wrapper script runs as 'mysql'. This can cause mysql_safe to not make the call to ulimit. In my case setting LimitNOFILE in SystemD didn't help - all it did was increase the file limit for the wrapper, but NOT for the daemon itself.
I found a two step process to get it working

Step 1 - re-instate the mysqld_safe section to the conf file so that mysql_safe will read it

```
sudo vi /etc/opt/rh/rh-mariadb100/my.cnf.d/mariadb-server.cnf
[mysqld_safe]
open_files_limit=2048
```

Step 2 - create a SystemD drop-in to start the wrapper as root (the daemon will still run as 'mysql'). Note that LimitNOFILE is commented out.

```
/etc/systemd/system
mkdir rh-mariadb100-mariadb.service.d
cd rh-mariadb100-mariadb.service.d
vi limits.conf
[Service]
#LimitNOFILE=2048
User=
Group=
```

Reload SystemD service files

```
systemctl daemon-reload
```

now restart the service, check value of open_files_limit in mysql client
it should now say 2048 (new soft limit)

The proper solution would probably be to get rid of the wrapper and use native SystemD.

**UPDATE**
it looks like this is fixed in the more recent version, which no longer uses the mysql_safe wrapper

```
rh-mariadb101-mariadb-10.1.19-6.el7.x86_64
```

Answer (score 0):

To increase open-files-limit in MySQL 5.6 on Centos 7 you must:

```
nano /usr/lib/systemd/system/mysqld.service
```

add at the end of the file:

```
LimitNOFILE=65535
LimitNPROC=65535
```

then:

```
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl restart mysqld
```

Done! , I assume that for MariaDB is the same thing

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that no other files exist in the:
/etc/systemd/system/mariadb.service.d
folder that might be limiting the number of files.
That was my case, there was another file that was reducing the limit I set :)